# Wrap the set of points to the minimum polygon

Tags: shapefile, point, algorithm, concave-hull, boundaries

Given I have a set of points which represents the circles which are intersected.
As result I'm trying to receive the boundary which represent the polygon which wraps all circles.

Please take a look to the picture below.
The inner black dots should be completely ignored. As result I'm trying to receive the set of dots which marked with red line.

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for a concave hull but to follow the circular outlines you will need to densify them or start looking into true curve support as well.

Comment: Many similar questions in this group http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=concave+hull

Comment: You've not found anything that 100% fits your requirement, but what **did** you find that was close? And why wasn't it close enough? And can you supply the dataset - or more than one dataset - of your points so we can test algorithms without having to digitise from your diagram?

Comment: There is no unique polygon that answers this question. You could look at min area, or min perimeter polygons that include all points. Neither would likely be ideal. Likely an optimal approach would involve Voronoi diagrams.

Comment: @PolyGeo is absolutely correct, you've drawn a concave hull, which is **really** not easy. If you want to do this you are going to need to do some programming and make some assumptions.. I can help (a bit) here but I need to know which API and programming/scripting language you are intending to use; If you're only after an algorithm look at creating a triangulation and decimating (removing) edge triangles based on longest edge.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson concave hulls, aka "alpha shapes" aren't that "difficult" - the only difficulty is choosing the one parameter that defines the concavity. There's code in R to do it.

Comment: Yes @Spacedman, they're not impossible, the hard part is defining your parameters to match your data. Without knowing if the OP has access to or experience in R I wouldn't suggest R; the way the question reads is a general algorithm which is slightly more difficult than calling R.ConcaveWhatever - the difficulty of this is dependent on their ability in mathematics and programming which is unknown and this is not a beginner python task.

Comment: I know there is an add-in for QGIS for concave hull that I use occasionally. As noted, the trick is that each data set will need different parameters to define what is an "external boundary" and even then to get good results you might need to do some preprocessing on your input data. ESRI doesn't have a stock tool for a reason, this is a spatial question that is not easily addressed with math when you break it down.